# How to monitoring thorntail resources by Java VisualVM

Tags: jvisualvm, thorntail

I want to monitor thorntail resources such as "how many thread are running at the moment". I add a user as ManagementRealm in management field of yml file.

```
  management:
      ManagementRealm:
        in-memory-authentication:
          users:
            admin:
              password: 123456
```

and, bind 0.0.0.0 for management interface.

```
  network:
    interfaces:
      management:
        bind: 0.0.0.0
```

My portOffset is 0 and I use port 9990 for connection. but, I received error in Java VisualVM.
How can i fix that?

Comment: Do you also have a dependency on the `management` fraction?

Comment: Like what? I don't think so

Comment: in Thorntail log:         
2019-11-26 21:17:12,457 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0060: Http management interface listening on http://0.0.0.0:9990/management
2019-11-26 21:17:12,457 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0054: Admin console is not enabled

Comment: At the very beginning of the log, do you have `THORN0013: Installed fraction:               Management - STABLE          io.thorntail:management:2.5.0.Final`?

Comment: Yes, Thank you for your help.
my problem was not adding 'jboss-client.jar' when i excuted jvisualvm and it's not a problem with thorntail

Comment: Glad you found the problem and made it work! :-)